# tooltip on sortable header cells of BootstrapVue table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I would like to add tooltips for some of the header cells of my BootstrapVue sortable table.  The table is tagged like this:

```
             <b-table 
                striped 
                small 
                hover 
                sticky-header
                sort-icon-left
                selectable
                id="search_results_table_id"
                select-mode="single"
                :items="person_list" 
                :fields="person_fields">
```

I tried to accomplish this using v-slot:head(), but wasn't able to make it work. Here is how my person_fields object is currently looking.

```
person_fields: [{key: 'name', label: 'Person ID', sortable: true, tooltip: 'Eureka!'},...],
```

And here was my v-slot:head...

Here is my v-slot:head...

```
<template v-slot:head()="data">                     
  <span v-b-tooltip.hover :title='data.tooltip'>{{ data.label}}           
  </span>                   
</template>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're binding your `title` to an undefined property inside your slot.

The `tooltip` property, is nested inside a `field` object, which contains all the data for the field.

```html
<template v-slot:head()="data">                     
  <span v-b-tooltip.hover :title='data.field.tooltip'>
    {{ data.label }}           
  </span>                   
</template>
```

Comment: Perfection!  That did it.  Thanks so much.